# How configure Apache to accept expired client certificate with TLS v1.2?

Tags: ios, apache, tls1.2, mdm

MacOS Server 5.7.1: I have a problem with a lot of devices with Mdm identity device certificate expired (for a bug of macOS Server before than 5.7.1 that didn't renew them)

At the moment the remote devices are not able to connect to server because the TLS 1.2 protocol check expiry date of client certificate. But to send a new certificate the connection should be completed, otherwise we have to reinitialize every iPad that should be remote controlled.

Do you know if there is a way to make OS X Apache to accept it?

```
<Location "/devicemanagement/mdm/mdm_connect">
 SSLRequireSSL
 SSLVerifyClient require
 SSLVerifyDepth 2
 SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData +StrictRequire +OptRenegotiate +LegacyCertChainVerify
 SSLRenegBufferSize 2097152
 RequestHeader set X-PM-REMOTE_ADDR          "%{REMOTE_ADDR}s"
 RequestHeader set X-PM-SSL_CLIENT_V_REMAIN  "%{SSL_CLIENT_V_REMAIN}s"
 RequestHeader set X-PM-SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN   "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}s"
 RequestHeader set X-PM-SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY    "%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}s"
 ProxyPass unix:/Library/Server/ProfileManager/Config/var/dmhttpd.sock|http://dmhttpd/devicemanagement/secure/mdm_connect
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured device checkin url to mandatory very certificate. If device certificates are expired you can  configure it as

```
SSLVerifyClient optional
```

And perform all the validation tasks in your servlets .

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. In my case too, there are clients with expired certificates which I need to allow. Looking at the HTTPD docs, I was thinking of using SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY as it should output "NONE, SUCCESS, GENEROUS or FAILED:reason".  My guess was if the validation is failing, I should be able to see it from FAILED:reason. In the logs I get this: [Sun Apr 23 11:16:31.047618 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 2955] [client 10.192.11.180:48138] AH02276: Certificate Verification: Error (10): certificate has expired [subject: